# Как использовать элемент в Listbox как кнопку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

У меня есть Listbox, заполненный названиями химических элементов, и при нажатии на эти названия должно открываться окошко с описанием элемента. Никак не могу задействовать названия в качестве кнопки. Код представлен ниже:
функция открытия листбокса:

```
def open_lstbx():
    lbox = Listbox(width = 300, height = 200)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(lbox, orient=VERTICAL)
    scrollbar.config(command=lbox.yview)
    lbox.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=N+E+S+W, ipady = 50)
    lbox.columnconfigure(0, weight = 0)
    lbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)   
    scrollbar.grid(sticky=E, padx = 300)
```

Заполнение листбокса названиями:

```
for i in english_names:
    lbox.insert(END, i)
```

Если что, english_names - это массив

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно привязаться к виртуальному событию `<<ListboxSelect>>`, которое срабатывает при выборе одного или нескольких элементов:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

lbox = Listbox(root)
lbox.pack()


def on_change(event):
    widget = event.widget  # виджет, с которым произошло событие (в данном случае listbox)
    selection = widget.curselection()  # получаем tuple из индексов выделенных элементов
    if selection:  # если что-то выделено (tuple не пустой)
        text = widget.get(selection[0])  # Текст в выбранной строке
        # выводим текст выделенного элемента в консоль
        print(text)
        # то же самое, но вывод в диалоговое окно
        messagebox.showinfo('Title', text)


lbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_change)

for i in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
    lbox.insert(END, i)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95391/discussion-on-answer-by-insolor-----listbox--).